# About svn update from Repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am working with large enterprise ejb application . And it is with SVN repository .
There are lots of files with changes in svn. But my current working copy is not updated . So, when i am trying to update from svn there is no updaete comming from svn, when click on update there are no update comming from SVN . But when i am showing diff between my current working copy and svn copy there are lots of changes. but i am not able to get those changes from svn .

i am also selecting option clean-up for clean up my working copy.

how can i got that all this update from svn forcefully. ?
please help me i have not much more experience with svn.

My version for SVN is: TortoiseSVN 1.6.7
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors? Did you try merging? any files that have now a .r[number] extension?

Comment: Which menu option do you use to find the differences between your working copy and the repository?

Comment: @rene... No, there is no error. It show me iption completed.

Comment: @Legolas.. Right click on folder->TortoiseSVN->Diff

Comment: Is it possible that you are inspecting the repository trunk but your working copy points to a branch (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @Alvaro G> VIncario .. I didnt understand what you mean say....? Please explain in deatil . I have not much more exp. with it.

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario .... how can i check that .....?

Answer (score 0):

If Subversion says your working copy is up-to-date, it's probably true. My guess is that your working copy points to a different repository path thank you think.

Right-click on your working copy's top folder and select `Properties`. The `Subversion` tab will tell you the exact path:

[image]

This situation can happen because it's a pretty common development pattern to have several copies of the complete project. See [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) for the complete details.

Comment: THanks a lot .... Thank you so much this will help me ......Actually i my working copy is directly from directory of svn while i show that there is trunk in svn  , so i think there is structure problem.

Comment: @downvoter: A `-1` means *This answer is not useful*. If you think so, you should care to explain why. Nobody wastes his time sending useless answers on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I get the following:

> If you want to see what changes you have made in your working copy, just use the explorer context menu and select TortoiseSVN → Diff.

So, may it be possible that you found a lot of local changes, and not changes within the repository?

You could try opening the repo browser from the context menu and inspect the remote repository from there to see which revision it is at.